# JwPlayer: HTML5 player not found

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, html, jwplayer

I am using JW Player to play videos. But its throwing Error loading player:
HTML5 player not found.

My Code:

```
 <%= jwplayer_assets %>
 <div id="mediaplayer", align="center">
 </div>
 <script type="text/javascript">jwplayer.key="wjl6yMFUQPDP";</script>
 <script type="text/javascript">


 jwplayer("mediaplayer").setup({
 flashplayer: "<%= asset_path('player.swf') %>", 
 file: "<%=@video_url%>",
 height: 360,
 width: 640
 });

 </script>
```

please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: You could check if jwplayer.html5.js is in the same location as jwplayer.js

Comment: @Chickenrice it's there in the same location

Comment: any error on the browser console?

Comment: its showing like No suitable players found and fallback enabled

Comment: What version jwplayer are you using?

Comment: jwplayer-rails (1.0.1)

Comment: Provide a link, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working copy.

You can clone or download it as zip file

```
https://github.com/shamsulsham89/jwplayer-rails3.2
```

and run it on your system. But update the browser to latest version so that it supports the html5 otherwise it will throw error.

Steps to run:

```
1> bundle install
2> rails s
```

Go to the **show page** after starting rails server from index page.

Comment: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/videos/192/jwplayer.html5.js"):

Comment: put jwplayer.html5.js in the folder vendor/assets/javascripts/ and add the line //= require jwplayer.html5 in application.js file

Comment: @poojaagarwal: i have updated my github repo for production environment and it is working.